# Экспорт и импорт БД из приложения

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть приложение, которое работает с БД.. Пытаюсь реализовать экспорт и импорт БД для переноса данных между приложениями.

Нашел код экспорта..

```
private void exportDatabase(){
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    FileChannel source=null;
    FileChannel destination=null;
    String currentDBPath = "/data/"+ "kitchen.book" +"/databases/"+"cookbook";
    String backupDBPath = "cookbook.db";
    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "DB Exported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Сам экспорт работает, БД экспортируется, но когда открываю ее, то там нет таблиц.. Почему? Хотя в приложении есть таблицы и они заполнены.

Comment: Вытащите из папки приложения оригинальный файл с базой(в студии есть Device File Explorer, по умолчанию справа внизу) и сравните побитово  с тем, что скопировалось на карту. Видимо копирование прошло неудачно. И еще уточните, вы просто sqlite используете? Не Room или Realm?

Comment: Там нет таблиц или файл вообще нулевой длины - может он только создан, но содержимое не скопировано? Так же, кроме файла бд могут быть ещё файлы журналов, и если вы никогда не закрывали базу, то данные могли остаться в них.

Comment: Я использую room

Comment: Возможно скопировалось неправильно.. но в бд из приложения есть данные..

Comment: По-моему путь к базе неправильный. И к тому же на разных устройствах он может отличаться - хардкодить его не советую, лучше спросить у контекста https://stackoverflow.com/a/55135337

Comment: Попробую спасибо